# Chain two jquery events

Tags: jquery

If I have an event handler like:

```
function A() {
 ...
}
```

it's possible to assign to more than one event:

```
$("#test1").keyup(A);
$("#test2").change(A);
```

But I'm wondering if it's possible to do it with only one sentence, something like:

```
$("#test1").keyup, $("#test2").change (function () {
  ...
});
```

Comment: You want the chain events that you declare on different IDs? What are you trying to do really?

Comment: I want to assign the same function to different IDs and different events for them (my case: a SELECT needs to respond to onChange event and text INPUT needs to respond to onKeyUp, but is the same funcion UpdateGraph who manages the event)

Comment: There is really no need to write it in a single chain, it will only make your code uglier, difficult to read, and possibly involve more jQuery function calls which is really a terrible idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer? No. Long answer? Not at all.

Sorry not to have the answer you were hoping for. But the good news is that your code looks spot-on aside from that limitation.

Comment: Answer is: yes, it can be done, see answer from @jacek-kaniuk below

Comment: @RensdeNobel: Answer is still No. At least not in the way OP wanted, with  specific element/trigger combinations triggering a function. You could, of course, listen for all the triggers/events you want to use, and all the elements those triggers/events might happen against, and then look at the event object to determine whether the right combination was detected, but it is probably easier just binding each combination separately.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#test2").bind('keyup change', A);
```

/edit as for different elements and events - it's:

```
$("#test1, #test2").bind('keyup change', A);
```

or

```
$("#test1").bind('keyup', A);
$("#test2").bind('change', A);
```

depending on what do You expect. There is no simpler way

Comment: They are 2 different elements. Everyone is jumping the gun here.

Comment: This would work to listen for those two events on elements matching the jQuery selector, but the OP is looking for two different events on two different elements. So only a "keyup" on "#test1" OR a "change" on "#test2", but not a "change" on "#test1".

Comment: @Jacek_FH - The second example of your edit would work. But then the OP may as well stick with what they currently have. The first example of your edit would bind both events to both elements.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, yes it is. It is really horrible though.

```
$("#test1").keyup(A).parent().find("#test2").change(A);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8RwZY/

There is also this atrocity:

```
$("#test1, #test2").eq(0).keyup(A).end().eq(1).change(A);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8RwZY/1/

Comment: Lol! I would suggest to never use such similar coding horrors.

Comment: @Jose Faeti - Totally agree. Unless you're trying to get somebody to quit :p

Answer (score 0):

If these were the same element, say `#test1`, then you can chain the methods

```
$('#test1').change(A).keyup(A);
```

However, with more than 1 element you can't chain them, or do anything else similar to your example.